# Vector perpendicular to a graph in a given point?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have this function:$$f(x,y)=2xy^2$$ and I have to find a vector perpendicular to the the graph of the function in the point $(2,1)$.
The gradient is $$\nabla{f(x,y)}=(2y^2,4xy)$$ and $$\nabla{f(2,1)}=(2,8)$$ but the answer is not correct.

Comment: It looks like you’re meant to be working in three dimensions, not two.

Comment: So it will be something like $(\nabla{ f(x,y)},z)$

Comment: Not quite. Write the equation of the surface in the form $F(x,y,z)=0$ and use the fact that the gradient of a function is always normal to its level surfaces.